# Текстура в Blender

Tags: blender

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток, я только начал изучать блендер и столкнулся с проблемой наложения текстур, присмотритесь на верхнюю часть выделенной области, как это возможно пофиксить???

Comment: Совершенно не разбираюсь ни в блендере, ни в анимации, но мне совершенно не понятно, в чём именно заключается проблема на скриншоте. Может всё-таки стоит словами описать?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>U</kbd> - Smart UV project.

А вообще я было бы неплохо изучить несколько уроков о том как накладываются текстуры

Например:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo&ab_channel=BlenderGuru